# Getting variable value out of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to extract value of a variable used in jQuery so that we can use it in JavaScript functions

```
<script>
var val;
$(document).ready(function() {$('.nav a').click(function(event) 
{event.preventDefault();
val=$(this).index();

if(val==0){

$('#hide_main').hide();
$('.main_BSNS').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')                                             


                    }//if val==0 ends here

                else if(val==1){

                    $('#hide_main').hide();
                    $('.main_ACTNT').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')                                                

                    }

                else if(val==2){

                    $('#hide_main').hide();
                    $('.main_devp').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')                                             


                    }




            });



        });
function getCookie(c_name){
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
if (x==c_name)
{
return unescape(y);
}
}
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("BSNS");
if (username!=null && username!="")
{
$('#hide_main').hide();
$('.main_BSNS').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')
}

else
{
alert(val);
if (username!=null && username!="")
{
setCookie("BSNS",username,365);
$('#hide_main').hide();
$('.main_BSNS').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')
}
}
}   
</script>
```

now i want this checkCookie() function to be called by  but the alert always show up with an undefined value (as many users predicted) but i am unable to find a solution to this and to write these cookies...(finally i am successful atleast to put my code on this website :-) )

Comment: i have tried putting the var x to global scope i.e. declaring it just after <script> tag and before document.ready but it still does not work at all

Comment: declaring a variable outside of a function will result in a global variable which is accessible everywhere.

Comment: but its not working...i really dont know why...i also tried making a global variable like
<script>
var globe
 $(document).ready(fucntion(){

var x=5;
globe=x;


});

function myFunction(){

alert(globe);

}

</script>

but it still does not work at all

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it "does not work"? Do you get any alert at all? Do you get any error message?

Comment: You realize jQuery is javascript...

Comment: You've posted broken code without much of an explanation about what you're trying to do.  Then you get frustrated in comments below because we can't figure out a problem you've failed to properly described.  Please read [this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [this](http://sscce.org) if you're interested in receiving quality help.  Meanwhile, I think this question should be closed.

Comment: Please learn some JavaScript fundamentals before jumping on JQuery

Comment: i have just updated my question according to the requiremet....but now i am unable to ask questions...i have read those terms...they asked me to fix the question...i have done that..please tell what else i should do to remove this ban

Answer (score 2):

Try fixing the syntax error caused by the missing brackets after myFunction. This will then work:

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="click me" />

<script>

var x;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    x=5;
});

function myFunction(){
    alert(x);
}

$('#mybutton').click(myFunction);

</script>
```

Comment: I was about to give you an up-vote, but then you used inline JavaScript.

Comment: @Sparky hmm fair dos. I've edited to make it more compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, `x` just needs to be a global variable:

```
<script>
var x;
$(document).ready(function(e){    
    x=5;
});

function myFunction(){    
    alert(x);
}

myFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: what if i call myFunction() with <body onload="myFunction()">....will it work???

Comment: Please do not fix the code in somebody else's answer.  Vote on the answer if it's incorrect, make a comment, and/or post your own answer.

Comment: @Sparky - why not fix code in someone elses answer when by posting my own answer I do nothing other than minor fix which would end up polluting the question with many similar answers?

Comment: Nemo64...what should i do in such a case??? i need to use value got from jquery variable to be used in a javascript function that is called by <body onload="function">

Comment: @user1926956 everything you do should be inside your ready event. Everything outside of your ready event should only be preparing... like initiating the variable.

Comment: @PaulSullivan, because that's not how we do things here.  It's not ok to change the code since you have no idea what the person intended.  You could be artificially boosting this user's reputation (Rep ~= Skill Level). Just post the correct answer yourself and if you want to help the person who answered, point out his mistake in a comment and/or vote on it.

Comment: is there any way to call this myFunction() when all of the page including the script is fully loaded and the value 5 is assigned to x???

Comment: @user1926956, **have you fixed your syntax error yet?**  `function myFunction{`, is likely the root of your whole problem. ( Missing the `()`. )

Comment: you guys are just discussing that i missed those brackets which is not the real problem...i did'nt put the actual code here as it was too lengthy to be formatted here for a newbie....i am just asking is there any way to assign the value of a variable in jquery code to a variable used in a function which is called by <body onload="myFunction()"....i have gone through all possible ways and spent like my whole day working on this but everytime i get value of the variable used in myFunction() to be undefined (as many users pointed out but no one is giving the solution to that)

Comment: @user1926956... that is **NOT** what you asked at all!  You posted code with syntax errors and no mention of `<body onload`.  People are trying to help you based on what little you described in your original posting.  You should be down-voted and this question closed.

Comment: @Paul Sullivan Thanks for pointing out the error. I didn't notice that when I copy/pasted the code from the question. I've updated the answer to include your change.

Comment: i am newbie for this site...infact this is my first post in which i posted some code :-(...i need help now as i have modified the question with the insertion of my actual code??/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is Javascript, it's just a matter of scope for the Javascript variable.

Make the variable global, then you can access it from the function also:

```
var x;

$(document).ready(function(e){    
    x = 5;
});

function myFunction() {    
    alert(x);
}
```

However, the `ready` event runs when the entore document has loaded, so the value is only available after the event handler has run. If you call the function before that, the value of the variable is still undefined.

Comment: you are missing () after myFunction

Comment: @PaulSullivan: Yes, you are right. I copied the code from the question, and didn't notice that error. I wonder if that is the first reason that the code "does not work"...

Comment: It probably was the reason for the OP not being able to access the global (which he probably did try)

Comment: You are close to what i am asking....pls tell me what if i call myFunction() with <body onload="myFunction()">....will it work???

Comment: @user1926956: Well, that will probably work. You may get a race condition in Internet Explorer, as it doesn't have a DOMReady event, so jQuery has to emulate it. There the `ready` event may come after the `onload` event in certain conditions.

Comment: you guys are just discussing that i missed those brackets which is not the real problem...i did'nt put the actual code here as it was too lengthy to be formatted here for a newbie....i am just asking is there any way to assign the value of a variable in jquery code to a variable used in a function which is called by <body onload="myFunction()"....i have gone through all possible ways and spent like my whole day working on this but everytime i get value of the variable used in myFunction() to be undefined (as many users pointed out but no one is giving the solution to that)

Comment: @user1926956... that is **NOT** what you asked at all!  You posted code with syntax errors and no mention of `<body onload`.  People are trying to help you based on what little you described in your original posting.  You should be down-voted and this question closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is just javascript scoping rules.  The x defined inside a function is not available outside.  You either need to pass that value to myFunction, or you need to define x in a scope that myFunction can see.

Comment: i have tried putting the var x to global scope i.e. declaring it just after <script> tag and before document.ready but it still does not work at all

Comment: Are you re-declaring the variable inside document.ready?  If you use 'var' on both instances, you are declaring a local variable inside document.ready which is separate from the global variable.

Comment: @beezir even declaring again inside `document.ready` that scope wouldn't be available in global function but the global `var` would

Answer (score 0):

multiple ways:

```
var x; // may be initiated with a value
$(document).ready(function(e){    
    x = 5;
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(e){    
    window.x = 5;
});
```

However the ready event has to fire before the value is in the variable. If you ask for it directly in your code you will get `undefined`.

I recommend to do **everything** inside your ready event. Then you also have access to your variable.

```
var x;
$(document).ready(function(e){    
    x=5;
    myFunction(); // call it here or later
});

function myFunction(){    
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: You missed the OP's syntax error.

Comment: The OP's, `function myFunction{`, is likely the root of his whole problem.  Missing the `()`.

Comment: you guys are just discussing that i missed those brackets which is not the real problem...i did'nt put the actual code here as it was too lengthy to be formatted here for a newbie....i am just asking is there any way to assign the value of a variable in jquery code to a variable used in a function which is called by <body onload="myFunction()"....i have gone through all possible ways and spent like my whole day working on this but everytime i get value of the variable used in myFunction() to be undefined (as many users pointed out but no one is giving the solution to that)

Comment: @user1926956... that is **NOT** what you asked at all!  You posted code with syntax errors and no mention of `<body onload`.  People are trying to help you based on what little you described in your original posting.  You should be down-voted and this question closed.

Comment: @user1926956 just added a note for that but I think you are missing a little of understanding for the time factor. The function you give jQuery will be executed after everything else was executed. That's why your variable isn't defined directly after you added the event.